# Flamingo RibbonBand: how to disable Ctrl+F1 functionality

Tags: java, swing, ribbon, radiance-flamingo

When you double-click on menu or press Ctrl+F1, ribbon will be hidden.
What is the easiest and most correct way to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to turn off ribbon's minimising functionality by one of the expected common ways (like setting some ribbon parameter).
Following code does the trick:

```
getRibbon().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("minimized")){
                getRibbon().setMinimized(false);
            }
        }
    });
```